# How do I create custom Mac osx notifications

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, notifications

I've recently built an app using Eclipse IDE, however, there is one thing I would like to add. Mac osx computers use a notification system that looks like the following:
[image: Notification System]

If anyone knows how to replicate this using Eclipse I would very much appreciate it if you were to help me. Extra credit if you also teach me how to add custom text. Thanks :D

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Java. There are terminal applications that do it, but not java.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel in this question there is a solution to send notification using commands use Runtime to execute it.

Comment: What sort of app? It is possible to do with an SWT app or an Eclipse RCP but not from a plain Java app unless you run a separate program as suggested in one of the other comments.

Comment: I think it's an Eclipse RCP